# Scanner return no new line in a while loop

Tags: java, network-programming

Snippet of the code

```
while(!((input = sc.nextLine()) != null)) {
            sc = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter(" ");
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                in[index] = sc.next();
                index++;
            }
            if (index < 3 || !in[0].equals("ping")) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Usage ping <destination> <port number missing> . . . ."
                                + in[0] + " " + in[1] + " " + in[2]);
            }
}
```

I want to keep reading user inputs but after the first iteration, i get no new line found. Scanner does not wait for the user input but rather advances on.
Thanks

Comment: Your while loop is saying while the input *isn't* not equal to null... too many negatives, I think...

Comment: _isn't_ null (EOF) because i want to keep reading user input

Comment: Look more carefully at your code. You've got a `!` at the start, and `!= null`. So you're checking that isn't isn't *not null*.

Answer (score 1):

Your top-level while loop is doing the opposite of what you want. First it sets `input` equal to `sc.nextLine()`, which is good. Then `input` is compared to `null`. If this comparison yields `true`, then you have input, which means that the loop should continue. However, you are then negating the result of that comparison, which makes the loop terminate when there is input.

Remove the exclamation point, and you should be good.

**EDIT**

On second thought, your inner while loop is exiting when `sc.hasNextLine()` returns `false`. After that, you will go through the conditional statement and return to the top. Since `sc.hasNextLine()` already returned `false`, of course `sc.nextLine()` will return `null`. The input has already ended in the inner loop, so the outer loop will exit as well.

Comment: @rich_AF I edited my answer to present a second possibility.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used buffered reader and the problem was solved. Scanner class is weird in java